# How to calculated percentages in SQL without using with..as?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the query:

```
select grade_c as grade, count(c.grade_c) as num from `tblCustomerFeedback` c 

join `tblOrders`o on c.`invoice_n`=o.`invoice_n` 

join `tblProducts` p on o.`productID_n`=p.`productID_n`

where productName_c LIKE "%Premier%" 

group by c.grade_c
```

Here is the result:

[image]

How to calculate percentages in the optimal way without using with .. as, as it's unavailable in this version of MySQL (5.6.10)?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade!  This is much easier with window functions.  In earlier versions, you can use variables:

```
select grade, num, num / total
from (select grade_c as grade, count(*) as num,
             (@sum := @sum + count(*)) as total
      from `tblCustomerFeedback` c join
           `tblOrders` o
           on c.`invoice_n` = o.`invoice_n` join
           `tblProducts` p
           on o.`productID_n` = p.`productID_n` cross join
           (select @sum := 0) params
      where productName_c LIKE "%Premier%" 
      group by c.grade_c
     ) g;
```